# Understanding a measurabiliy statement from Section 6.3 in Lehmann and Romano

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, proof-explanation, statistical-inference, measurable-functions

This paragraph is at the end of Section 6.3 in the book *Testing Statistical Hypotheses* by Lehmann and Romano:

> In most applications, $M(x)$ is a measurable function taking on values in a
> Euclidean space and it is convenient to take $\mathcal B$ as the class of Borel sets. If $\phi(x) = \psi[M(x)]$ is then an arbitrary measurable function depending only on $M(x)$, it
> is not clear that $\psi(m)$ is necessarily $\mathcal B$-measurable. This measurability can be
> concluded if $\mathcal X$ is also Euclidean with $\mathcal A$ the class of Borel sets, and if the range of $M$ is a Borel set. We shall prove it here only under the additional assumption
> (which in applications is usually obvious, and which will not be verified explicitly
> in each case) that there exists a vector-valued Borel-measurable function $Y(x)$
> such that $[M(x), Y (x)]$ maps $\mathcal X$ onto a Borel subset of the product space $\mathcal M\times \mathcal Y$, that this mapping is $1 : 1$, and that the inverse mapping is also Borel-measurable. Given any measurable function $\phi(x)$ of $x$, there exists then a measurable function $\phi'$ of $(m, y)$ such that $\phi(x) ≡ \phi' [M(x), Y (x)]$. If $\phi$ depends only on $M(x)$, then $\phi'$ depends only on $m$, so that $\phi'$ $(m, y) = \psi(m)$ say, and $\psi$ is a measurable function of $m$.

I don't understand how to formalize the argument:

1. How to choose $\phi'$?
2. Why $\phi'$ depends only on $m$ if $\phi$ depends only on $M(x)$ ?
3. Where do we need $Y(x)$ to be 1:1 with measurable inverse and measurable range?

Can someone clarify the argument?

---

Edit: Why is $\psi(m)$ a measurable function of $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h$ be the function given by $h(x)=(M(x),Y(x))$. By assumption, the range of $h$ is a Borel set and has a measurable inverse $h^{-1}$ defined on the range which is where we need that $h$ is 1-to-1. For all $x$, we must have $h^{-1}(h(x))=x$. So we can define $\phi'$ as $\phi\circ h^{-1}$. Then $\phi(x)=\phi(h^{-1}(h(x)))=\phi'(h(x))=\phi'(M(x),Y(x))$. Also, $\phi'$ is measurable as a composition of measurable functions.

That $\phi$ depends only on $M(x)$ means that $M(x)=M(x')$ implies $\phi(x)=\phi(x').$ Since $\phi'(M(x),Y(x))=\phi(x)=\phi(x')=\phi'(M(x'),Y(x'))$, this implies that $\phi'(M(x),Y(x))=\phi(x)=\phi(x')=\phi'(M(x'),Y(x'))$ whenever $M(x)=M(x')$. And that means that $\phi'$ depends only on $m=M(x)$.

Comment: Ok got that. But why $\phi(x)=\psi(M(x)))$ ? It seems the authors are defining $\psi(m)$ as a section of $\phi'$.

Comment: Please don't edit questions so that correct answers look inappropriate. The definition of $\psi$ is pinned down by the condition. That $\psi$ is measurable follows from $\phi'^{-1}(B)=\{(M(x),Y(x)):\phi'(M(x),Y(x))\in A\}=(\psi^{-1}(A)\times\text{range}(Y))\cap\text{range}(h)$.

Comment: I reverted back my edit. Sorry I don't understand: Why is $\psi^{-1}(B)$ is a measurable set?

Comment: The point is that if you look at preimages of $\phi'$, only the first coordinate matters if everything depends only on $M(x)$. This means that, up to range restrictions, the preimage has a product form as a rectangle and such rectangeles are measurable exactly if each coordinate component is. One of these is the preimage under $\psi$.

Comment: 1. How do you conclude $\psi^{-1}(A)\times\text{range}(Y)$ is measurable in product space (without the range restriction)? 2. "*Rectangles are measurable exactly if each coordinate component is*" Is this always true in any product space?

Comment: The range of $Y$ need actually not be a Borel set. But you can extend $\phi'$ measurably to the product space of the codomains of $M$ and $Y$ respectively in an arbitrary way. If you do it so it does not map into elements of $A$, you can replace the range of $Y$ by the codomain. And yes, each component of a measurable rectangle must be measurable. These are sections and their measurability is proven when one proves Fubini's theorem for the product-$\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Ok but I still don't see how to deal with $\text{range}(h)$, because $(\psi^{-1}(A)\times\text{range}(Y))\cap\text{range}(h)$ is not a rectangle. Could you add details?

Comment: The range of $h$ is measurable to begin with. The annoying issue is that the authors do not specify the domain and codomain of their functions. This is why it is essier to extend the functions to be defined on larger spaces. And for a more direct solution, you can google "Doob-Dynkin lemma."

Comment: Can we chat about this? I don't see how you can conclude that $\psi^{-1}(A)$ is measurable from $\phi'^{-1}(A)= (\psi^{-1}(A)\times\text{range}(Y))\cap\text{range}(h)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151491/discussion-between-michael-greinecker-and-alphie).

Comment: Exactly the case $M(x)=Y(x)=x$ is problematic because the range of $h$ is not a rectangle. If the range of $h$ is a rectangle then its ok right?

Comment: @Alphie Yes. The result should still "almost" hold by using a slightly more permissible measurability notion under which projections of Borel sets are measurable. The LR argument seems to have a gap, though,